# Connecting a component with OwnProps using react redux and typescript in the .NET Core 2.0 reactredux template project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, typescript-typings, asp.net-core-2.0

Source code can be found here: https://github.com/cvanem/ASPNETCoreReact16Redux

EDIT: I was able to get it 99% working with the below code. Everything runs when compiled, but when using  in a parent component it gives a warning that the Property count is missing.  When actually executed, everything works as expected. This count property is in the CounterStore and correctly increments when the button is pressed.  Everything works, but I am not sure how to get rid of the typescript warning.  Did I do a type definition wrong somewhere?  The original template had as typeof Counter  added to the end of the connect statement like this:

```
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapStateToDispatch )(Counter) as typeof Counter;
```

When I try the above with my code, it gives the following error:

```
    ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/Counter.tsx:39:16 
        TS2352: Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<CounterState & ComponentProps & { increment: () => IncrementCountAction; decr...' cannot be converted to type 'typeof Counter'.
    ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/Counter.tsx:39:16 
        TS2352: Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<CounterState & ComponentProps & { increment: () => IncrementCountAction; decr...' cannot be converted to type 'typeof Counter'.
        Type 'Component<Pick<CounterState & ComponentProps & { increment: () => IncrementCountAction; decrement...' is not comparable to type 'Counter'.
Types of property 'setState' are incompatible.
          Type '{ <K extends never>(f: (prevState: Readonly<ComponentState>, props: Pick<CounterState & Component...' is not comparable to type '{ <K extends never>(f: (prevState: Readonly<{}>, props: CounterState & ComponentProps & { increme...'.
            Types of parameters 'f' and 'f' are incompatible.
              Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
                Type 'Pick<CounterState & ComponentProps & { increment: () => IncrementCountAction; decrement: () => De...' is not comparable to type 'CounterState & ComponentProps & { increment: () => IncrementCountAction; decrement: () => Decreme...'.
                  Type 'Pick<CounterState & ComponentProps & { increment: () => IncrementCountAction; decrement: () => De...' is not comparable to type 'CounterState'.
                    Property 'count' is missing in type 'Pick<CounterState & ComponentProps & { increment: () => IncrementCountAction; decrement: () => De...'.
     ERROR in [at-loader] ./ClientApp/components/Home.tsx:16:13 
        TS2322: Type '{ test: "hello"; children: never[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Counter> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & R...'.
          Type '{ test: "hello"; children: never[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<CounterState & ComponentProps & { increment: () => IncrementCountAction; decrement: () =...'.
            Property 'count' is missing in type '{ test: "hello"; children: never[]; }'.
```

Here is what I have, which compiles and works, but still gives a design time warning:

```
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapStateToDispatch )(Counter);
```

Any Ideas?  Here is the full component code with everything but still gives the the typescript warning at design time when the Counter component is consumed by a parent component (i.e ):

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { Link, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { ApplicationState }  from '../store';
    import * as CounterStore from '../store/Counter';        

    type ComponentStateProps = CounterStore.CounterState & ComponentProps; //type definition for component props merged with state props (for typings on the connect function)
    type CounterProps = ComponentStateProps & typeof CounterStore.actionCreators; 
    //type definition for the component class

    interface ComponentProps {
        test: string;
    }

    class Counter extends React.Component<CounterProps, {}> {
        public render() {
            return <div>
                <h1>Counter</h1>

                <p>This is a simple example of a React component.</p>

                <p>Current count: <strong>{ this.props.count }</strong></p>
        <button onClick={() => { this.props.increment() 
    }}>Increment</button>      
                <p>Component Prop = {this.props.test}</p>
            </div>;
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState, ownProp: ComponentProps): 
    ComponentStateProps => {
        return (
            {
                ...state.counter,
                test: ownProp.test      
            }
        );
    };

    const mapStateToDispatch = CounterStore.actionCreators;

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapStateToDispatch )(Counter);
```

---

Original Post:

I have created a new react redux project from the Visual Studio 2017 template by running this from the command prompt:

> dotnet new reactredux

I am trying to connect a component to the redux store.  The component has it's own properties, ComponentProps.  When I try to connect it to the store with it's own properties, I get the following error:

```
./ClientApp/components/Counter.tsx:34:5 

TS2345: Argument of type '(state: ApplicationState) => CounterState' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MapStateToPropsParam<{}, ComponentProps,>'.

Type '(state: ApplicationState) => CounterState' is not assignable to type 'MapStateToProps<{}, ComponentProps, {}>'.

Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ApplicationState'.
Property 'counter' is missing in type '{}'.
```

I added the ComponentProps interface, includeded it in CounterProps and added it to the connect call at the bottom.  Here is the Component code:

```
    import * as React from 'react';
    import { Link, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { ApplicationState }  from '../store';
    import * as CounterStore from '../store/Counter';
    import * as WeatherForecasts from '../store/WeatherForecasts';

    interface ComponentProps {
        test: string;
    }

    type CounterProps =
    CounterStore.CounterState
        & typeof CounterStore.actionCreators
        & RouteComponentProps<{}>
        & ComponentProps;   

    class Counter extends React.Component<CounterProps, {}> {
        public render() {
            return <div>
                <h1>Counter</h1>

                <p>This is a simple example of a React component.</p>

                <p>Current count: <strong>{ this.props.count }</strong></p>

                <button onClick={ () => { this.props.increment() } 
    }>Increment</button>
            </div>;
        }
    }

    // Wire up the React component to the Redux store
    export default connect<{}, {}, ComponentProps>(
        (state: ApplicationState) => state.counter, // Selects which state properties are merged into the component's props
        CounterStore.actionCreators, // Selects which action creators are merged into the component's props
    )(Counter) as typeof Counter;
```

Can someone please tell me the correct way to use connect to connect a component that has it's own properties to a store?  Everything I try seems to generate an error.  The @types/react-redux file has a note about passing a 3rd parameter and saying that the user must extend the ownProps interface, but I am not exactly sure how to do that.  Here is the section from the index.d.ts file for @types/react-redux:

```
    /**
     * Connects a React component to a Redux store.
     *
     * - Without arguments, just wraps the component, without changing the behavior / props
     *
     * - If 2 params are passed (3rd param, mergeProps, is skipped), default behavior
     * is to override ownProps (as stated in the docs), so what remains is everything that's
     * not a state or dispatch prop
     *
     * - When 3rd param is passed, we don't know if ownProps propagate and whether they
     * should be valid component props, because it depends on mergeProps implementation.
     * As such, it is the user's responsibility to extend ownProps interface from state or
     * dispatch props or both when applicable
     *
     * @param mapStateToProps
     * @param mapDispatchToProps
     * @param mergeProps
     * @param options
     */
    export interface Connect {
        (): InferableComponentEnhancer<DispatchProp<any>>;

        <TStateProps = {}, no_dispatch = {}, TOwnProps = {}, State = {}>(
            mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, TOwnProps, 
            State>): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TStateProps & 
            DispatchProp<any>, TOwnProps>;

        <no_state = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}>(
            mapStateToProps: null | undefined,
            mapDispatchToProps: MapDispatchToPropsParam<TDispatchProps, 
            TOwnProps>
            ): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TDispatchProps, 
            TOwnProps>;

        <TStateProps = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}, State = {}>(
            mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, TOwnProps, 
            State>,: MapDispatchToPropsParam<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>
            ): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TStateProps & 
            TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>;

        <TStateProps = {}, no_dispatch = {}, TOwnProps = {}, TMergedProps = 
            {}, State = {}>(: MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, TOwnProps, 
            State>,: null | undefined,: MergeProps<TStateProps, undefined, 
            TOwnProps, >,<TMergedProps, TOwnProps>;

        <no_state = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}, TMergedProps = 
            {}>(: null | undefined,: MapDispatchToPropsParam<TDispatchProps, 
            TOwnProps>,: MergeProps<undefined, TDispatchProps, TOwnProps, 
            TMergedProps>,<TMergedProps, TOwnProps>;

        <no_state = {}, no_dispatch = {}, TOwnProps = {}, TMergedProps = {}>
            (: null | undefined,: null | undefined,: MergeProps<undefined, 
            undefined, TOwnProps, TMergedProps>,<TMergedProps, TOwnProps>;

        <TStateProps = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}, TMergedProps 
             = {}, State = {}>(: MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, 
             TOwnProps, State>,: MapDispatchToPropsParam<TDispatchProps, 
             TOwnProps>,: MergeProps<TStateProps, TDispatchProps, TOwnProps, 
             TMergedProps>,<TMergedProps, TOwnProps>;

        <TStateProps = {}, no_dispatch = {}, TOwnProps = {}, State = {}>(
             mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, TOwnProps, 
             State>,: null | undefined,: null | undefined,: Options<State, 
             TStateProps, TOwnProps>): 
             InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<DispatchProp<any> & 
             TStateProps, TOwnProps>;

        <TStateProps = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}>(
             mapStateToProps: null | undefined,: 
             MapDispatchToPropsParam<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>,
             mergeProps: null | undefined,: Options<{}, TStateProps, 
             TOwnProps><TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>;

        <TStateProps = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}, State = {}>(
             mapStateToProps: MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, TOwnProps, 
             State>,: MapDispatchToPropsParam<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>,
             mergeProps: null | undefined,: Options<State, TStateProps, 
             TOwnProps>): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TStateProps & 
             TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>;

        <TStateProps = {}, TDispatchProps = {}, TOwnProps = {}, TMergedProps 
             = {}, State = {}>(mapStateToProps: 
             MapStateToPropsParam<TStateProps, TOwnProps, 
             State>,mapDispatchToProps: 
             MapDispatchToPropsParam<TDispatchProps, TOwnProps>,
             mergeProps: MergeProps<TStateProps, TDispatchProps, TOwnProps, 
             TMergedProps>,
             options: Options<State, TStateProps, TOwnProps, TMergedProps>
             ): InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps<TMergedProps, 
             TOwnProps>;
}
```

Comment: Hey, did you manage to resolve this problem? I've got same issue. Everything's good until I try to use component within other one. It's like i need to pass all the props that @connect should provide internally. Unless I've got something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using some `Domain`:

```
    export type DomainState = Readonly<{
        isLoaded: boolean;
        isLoadedError: boolean;
        model: IDomainModel;
        error: any;
    }>;

    export interface IDomainStore {
        domain: DomainState;
    }

    interface IDomainPageCompProps extends 
        RouteComponentProps<IDomainRoutingParams> {
        isLoadedError: boolean;
        isLoaded: boolean;
        resources: any;
    }

    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { IDomainPageCompProps, DomainPage } from '...';
    import { IDomainStore } from '../store';
    import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router';
    import { IDomainRoutingParams } from '../types/routing-params';

    interface IOwnProps extends RouteComponentProps<IDomainRoutingParams> {
        resources;
    }

    const connected = connect<IDomainPageCompProps, {}, IOwnProps, IDomainStore>(
        (store: IDomainStore, ownProps: IOwnProps) => {
            return {
                ...ownProps,
                isLoaded: store.domain.isLoaded,
                isLoadedError: store.domain.isLoadedError
            };
        },
        (/* dispatch */) => {
            return {};
        }
    )(DomainPage);
    export const DomainPageContainer = withRouter(connected);


    // .jsx
    <Provider store={store}>
        <DomainPageContainer resources={...} />
    </Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
import { ApplicationState } from '../store';
import * as CounterStore from '../store/Counter';

interface AdditionalProps {
    exampleProps: string
}

type CounterProps =
    CounterStore.CounterState &
    typeof CounterStore.actionCreators &
    RouteComponentProps<{}> & 
    AdditionalProps;

class Counter extends React.PureComponent<CounterProps> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <h1>Counter</h1>

                <p>This is a simple example of a React component.</p>

                <p aria-live="polite">Current count: <strong>{this.props.count}</strong></p>

                <p>exampleProps: {this.props.exampleProps}</p>

                <button type="button"
                    className="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
                    onClick={() => { this.props.increment(); }}>
                    Increment
                </button>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
};

export default connect(
    (state: ApplicationState, ownProps: AdditionalProps) => {
        return {
            ...state.counter,
            ...ownProps
        }
    },
    CounterStore.actionCreators
)(Counter as any);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).